# password field data gets clear after submitting

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am uisng Django's `auth_user` table for username and password.To change the password field i did the below in forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

After changing my password field widget to `PasswordInput`,whatever password i enter gets cleared if i press save button.I tested it,the data gets saved in db,i am able to login using the same username and password.

template.py

```
<tr>
    <td>Password</td><td>{{registerform.password}}*                                
</tr>
```

Clarification:Before changing the password widget,the value entered are displayed in the field as same and not cleared in the field if i save.

After changing the password widget i am getting this issue.Password is showing in bullet point symbol but if i hit save button,entered password gets cleared from that field(field become empty but it is saving in model)

What would be the problem for this.

Thanks

Comment: I checked the views codes also,i am still not clear why this problem is occuring can any one tell me how to sort it out/what i did wrong

Comment: You mean that you password not displaying after you submit and return it to template? If so that is right and expected behaviour. password field not intended for returning/showing user password, only for saving

Comment: I am not getting,where was the problem with views,how to fix this.

Comment: I dont understand. Where you are not getting it. You said that it saves - than it mean you are getting it. You cant return password back to page with password field.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behaviour, of course. You do not want the password to be returned to the user: that would be a security risk. Displaying a blank edit box is the right thing to do.

Comment: Care to explain in what manner is that a security risk?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do like this.

```
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=True,))
```

Comment: you reeeeeally dont want this, sending the password back to the user is a security risk as  Daniel says, also the browsers will try to remember the password almost every time you save that form.